# Create a custom LoadBalancing Policy for spark cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, load-balancing, spark-cassandra-connector

I know that the spark-cassandra connector comes with its own default loadbalancing policy implementation(DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy). How can I go about implementing my own custom LoadBalancing class? I want to have the application use the WhiteListRoundRobin policy. What steps would I need to take? I'm still a newbie in working with spark and Cassandra and I would appreciate any guidance in this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into implementation of [LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy.scala#L28) - basically you need to create (if it doesn't exist) a class inherited from `LoadBalancingPolicy`, and implement your required logic for load balancing.

Then you need to create a class implementing `CassandraConnectionFactory` that will configure Cassandra session with required load balancing implementation. The simplest way is to take the code of [DefaultConnectionFactory](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/cql/CassandraConnectionFactory.scala#L43), but instead of using `LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy`, specify your load balancing class.

And then you specify that connection factory class name in the `spark.cassandra.connection.factory` configuration property.